# How can I find a syntax error in JAGS considering that the position indicated is not the real error position?

Tags: r, jags

I am trying to adjust a model in `jags`. I have a syntax error, but I've been trying to find it for hours. Please, any help is welcome. Here is the model

```
library(jagsUI)
nyears<-8

ad<-c(707,768,149,221,329, 222,869,445)
an<-c(327,257,18,10,49,56,323,211)

# Specify model in BUGS language

cat(file ="recipm.bug","

model {
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#            define the priors of the unknown parameters
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
  tau.juv <- pow(sigma.y, -2)
  sigma.juv ~ dunif(0, 20)
  sigma2.juv <- pow(sigma.an, 2)

#initial population sizes
Njuv ~ (300,0.0001) I (0,) #tamanio inicial de la poblacion de aniales
Nad ~ (700, 0.0001)I(0,) #tamanio inicial de la poblacion de adultos

#survival probabilities and productivity
  for (t in 1:(nyears-1)){
    sjuv[t] <- mean.sjuv
    sad[t]  <- mean.sad
    f[t]    <- mean.fec
    }

mean.sjuv ~ dunif(0, 0.6)
mean.sad ~ dunif(0.85,0.95 )
mean.fec ~ dunif(0, 1)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                           derived parameters
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Population recruitment traditional way
for (t in 1:(nyears-1)){
  rec [t]<-an[t]/ad[t]*0.5
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#               The likelihoods of the single data sets
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 3.1. Likelihood for population population count data (state-space
#model)

# 3.1.1 System process

for (t in 2:nyears){
  mean.juv[t] <- f[t-1] / 2 * sjuv[t-1] * Nad[t]
  Njuv[t]  ~  dpois(mean1[t])
 }


# 3.1.2 Observation process
for (t in 1:nyears){
  an[t] ~ dpois (mean(Njuv))
  ad[t] ~ dbin(Nad[t], tauy)
 }
}

",fill = TRUE)



# Bundle data
bugs.data <- list( ad=ad,an=an,nyears = 8)

# Initial values
inits <- function(){list(mean.sjuv = runif(1, 0, 1), mean.sad = runif
                         (1, 0, 1), mean.fec = runif(1, 0, 10),
                         Njuv = rpois(1,5), Nad = rpois(1,20), sigma.juv = runif
                         (1, 0, 10))}

parameters<-c("mean.sjuv","mean.sad","mean.fec", "N1","Njuv")

# MCMC settings
ni <- 20000
nt <- 6
nb <- 5000
nc <- 3

# Call jags from R
ipm <- jags(data = bugs.data, inits,  n.chains = nc,parameters.to.save = parameters,
            model.file = "recipm.bug", n.thin = nt, n.iter = ni, n.burnin = nb)
```

I am getting the following error `

```
Error in jags.model(file = model.file, data = data, inits = inits, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
  
Error parsing model file:
syntax error on line 18 near "("
```

I know that JAGS is a declarative language and consequently, to position indicated in the warning may not be the position of the error, any idea of strategies to find this kind of error?
Regards

Comment: Are you missing a distribution for `Njuv` and `Njuv`?

Comment: ... that should of been `Njuv` and `Nad`